# Adding error messages

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and was just wondering if there is a better way to write the following OR if it would make any difference to use `elseif` here instead of multiple `if` statements - especially if the options in questions might be more than in the example here (the current code is working).

**Note:** I cannot use `switch` here since the haystack string can contain multiple of the needle strings.

```
$errorList .= "Some text <ul>";
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "emailInvalid") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "passLength") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "passLowerCase") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "passUpperCase") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "passNumberSymbol") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
    if(strpos($errorDetails, "passMatch") !== false){
        $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
    }
$errorList .= "</ul>";
echo $errorList;
```

Comment: Would a switch without breaks be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks ! Good idea. I could live with that. Is that something you would suggest instead and prefer compared to elseif ?

Comment: I do not know what idiomatic PHP would be, I'm not an expert. But I have seen a lot of switches in my life, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea but since I am new to this (and my current code is working) I am trying to find the best solution here so I'll leave this open to see if someone is more certain about it. Hope that's ok.

Comment: I am downvoting this question because `<li>Some text</li>` is not, or will not be, your real code. As noted in the help center, Code Review prefers *real* code.

Comment: @Mast I don't think a switch without breaks would work.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: A downvote because I am not posting real text from my website ??

Comment: @keewee279 Honestly, yes. It was either that or a close vote, but I felt that it was still possible to review it. See [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/why-is-hypothetical-example-code-off-topic-for-code-review). If you want to discuss more about this and want me to explain my downvote further, you are welcome to chat in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 9):

I would use an associative array (also known as  a "map" or "dictionary" in other languages).

```
$errorMessages = array('emailInvalid' => 'Invalid email',
    'passLength' => 'invalid password length',
    'passLowerCase' => 'missing lower case character in password'
    // and so on...
);
```

Then I would loop across this map:

```
foreach ($errorDetails as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($errorDetails, $key) !== false) {
        $errorList .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
}
```

#### strpos

Storing your error-message stubs in `$errorDetails` is inefficient. `strpos` loops through the string each time. I'd recommend to instead append your error messages to an array, which would open up the possibility of looking up the full error message from something like `emailInvalid` with a O(1) complexity.

#### How did I know it was a map that was needed?

Let's look at this code:

```
if(strpos($errorDetails, "emailInvalid") !== false){
    $errorList .= "<li>Some text</li>";
}
if(strpos($errorDetails, "passLength") !== false){
    $errorList .= "<li>Some (other) text</li>";
}
```

There are two things that differs here, these parts can be simplified to:

```
if (strpos($errorDetails, $xxxxxxx) !== false) {
    $errorList .= $yyyyyyy;
}
```

To clean up this code, we could extract a method and call that multiple times, such as:

```
addErrorList($errorDetails, 'emailInvalid', 'invalid e-mail');
addErrorList($errorDetails, 'passLength', 'invalid password length');
...
```

However, this is still not very nice. **A map / associative array** contains a `key` to `value` mapping, which is precisely what you have here. For each specific error detail key, there is an associated error message. So add those values to an associative array and then loop through it.

Answer (score 6):

To add just a little bit to @Simon's excellent answer:

> I [...] was just wondering [...] if it would make any difference to use elseif here instead of multiple if statements

Uhm, yes, it would probably not do what you want: after any of the `if` statements are true, all the `elseif` not be evaluated, so only one error type would be printed at a time.

Another small thing, instead of accumulating all the error messages in `$errorList`, you could echo them directly.

Comment: Thanks for this ! If I would echo them directly how would I manage that they appear as an unordered list ?